# Change class of list of li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried for changing the class name of li with class `each_feature` to each_feature--display.On each click of load more I need to change class for next 3 li inside ul.

But the below javascript is not working for me. On load I called load_more.display_items() this also doesn't work.

Someone please help me to make this work

```
   <div class="export">
        <section class="container">
            <h2> Components Identified by scanner</h2>
             <ul class="components_features">
                <li class="each_feature">
                    <a href="//Nginx.com" target="_blank" title="Nginx" >
                        <h2 class="tech_name">
                            Nginx
                        </h2>
                        </a>
                        <div class="octo">
                            <div class="octo1">
                        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2441/3657346647_a11111ed39_z.jpg?zz=1" alt="" width="320" height="316" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="each_feature">
                    <a href="//Nginx.com" target="_blank" title="Nginx" >
                        <h2 class="tech_name">
                            Nginx
                        </h2>
                        </a>
                        <div class="octo">
                            <div class="octo1">
                        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2441/3657346647_a11111ed39_z.jpg?zz=1" alt="" width="320" height="316" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="each_feature">
                    <a href="//Nginx.com" target="_blank" title="Nginx" >
                        <h2 class="tech_name">
                            Nginx
                        </h2>
                        </a>
                        <div class="octo">
                            <div class="octo1">
                        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2441/3657346647_a11111ed39_z.jpg?zz=1" alt="" width="320" height="316" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="each_feature">
                    <a href="//Nginx.com" target="_blank" title="Nginx" >
                        <h2 class="tech_name">
                            Nginx
                        </h2>
                        </a>
                        <div class="octo">
                            <div class="octo1">
                        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2441/3657346647_a11111ed39_z.jpg?zz=1" alt="" width="320" height="316" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="each_feature">
                    <a href="//Nginx.com" target="_blank" title="Nginx" >
                        <h2 class="tech_name">
                            Nginx
                        </h2>
                        </a>
                        <div class="octo">
                            <div class="octo1">
                        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2441/3657346647_a11111ed39_z.jpg?zz=1" alt="" width="320" height="316" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="each_feature">
                    <a href="//Nginx.com" target="_blank" title="Nginx" >
                        <h2 class="tech_name">
                            Nginx
                        </h2>
                        </a>
                        <div class="octo">
                            <div class="octo1">
                        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2441/3657346647_a11111ed39_z.jpg?zz=1" alt="" width="320" height="316" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <a class="link" onclick="load_more.show_more_items()">
                    <span >Load more ...</span>
                </a>
                <hr>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 var load_more = {
            el: $('.export .components_features'),
            list_index: 3,
            display_items: function() {
                if((this.list_index + 3) > this.el.find('.each_feature').length) {
                    this.el.find('.each_feature').addClass('each_feature--display');


                }

                this.el.find('.each_feature:lt(' + this.list_index + ')').addClass('each_feature--display');
            },
            show_more_items: function() {
                this.list_index += 3;

                this.display_items();

            }
        }
```

Comment: What about just `$('.each_feature').addClass('each_feature--display')`?

Comment: And what isn't working? you have anchors that open in a new tab, yet nothing to prevent the default action, and then inline event handlers when you could be using jQuery instead, does the functions even get called?

Comment: That is to change of class of every each_feature to each_feature--display class @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @javvajikiran Isn't that what you want? - *"changing the class name of li with class each_feature to each_feature--display"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? Made in pure JS. For the a tag, you might want to prevent default link action if you are going to put a href.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .feature{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function loadMore(){
        features = document.getElementsByClassName("feature");

        if(features.length > 0){
            var count = 0;

            while(features.length && count < 3){
                count++;
                features[0].className = "featureDisplay";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="feature">
            1
        </li>
        <li class="feature">
            2
        </li>
        <li class="feature">
            3
        </li>
        <li class="feature">
            4
        </li>
        <li class="feature">
            5
        </li>
        <li class="feature">
            6
        </li>
        <a onclick="loadMore()">Load more ...</a>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with using a for loop is that the value returned is a node list list which is a live object and it messes up the array when you modify a class. Read more about it here: [javascript changes one some class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087202/javascript-changes-one-some-class-names)

Comment: Does features = document.getElementsByClassName("feature"); this selects all li in correct as listed in html.Because for me those are not displaying as per that order?

Comment: It selects every element that has the class "feature" and changes it to the class "feature_display". It creates an array of elements with the first encounter of the class as the first element of the array. Of course, change the variables and names and convert to JQuery for your needs. I will show you in the post

Comment: Sry I didn't got what u said, can u please explain with some example that would me more helpful, Thanks

Comment: You are right the order is wrong :( Will fix and post the whole thing here

Comment: There was a problem with changing the class and the array returned by getElementsByClassName. Fixed using a while loop! Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

on the 'load more' do this

```
            $(".each_feature").addClass('each_feature--display');
            $(".each_feature--display").removeClass('each_feature');
```

Of course you will have to adapt the code

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can do a switchClass() too